# `tmap` basemap in `plot` mode

Tags: raster, r, plot

I have a raster and I'd like to underlie it with a basemap in `tmap`. In the `view`-mode this kind of happens automatically. But when I set it to `plot`-mode I really struggle to get a basemap. Anyone maybe has a pointer on where to look?

I thought about something like this:

```
tm_shape(raster1) + tm_raster("col1.VALUE", palette = "viridis") + 
tm_basemap("Stamen.Watercolor") + tm_tiles("Stamen.TonerLabels")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rosm` package can download tiles from OpenStreetMap and construct an RGB raster that you can use as the first layer in a `tmap` plot.

For some raster `r`, something like [untested precisely]:

```
 x <- osm.raster(r, crop=TRUE)
 tm_shape(x) + tm_rgb() + tm_shape(r) + tm_raster()
```

will map `r` over the basemap image `x`.