# How can you overlay raster data on a stamenmap in R?

Tags: raster, r, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to overlay an image output from Google Earth Engine (.tif) on a basemap obtained using get_stamenmap {ggmap}.

The object returned by get_stamenmap doesn't have a coordinate reference system (calling crs(some_stamenmap) returns 'NA'). I infer that the object returned by get_stamenmap uses Google's PseudoMercator projection, because whatever it's using plays fine with feature data output from GEE

(Aside to explain what I mean but that: if I export a featureCollection from GEE, read into R, extract the long/lat data from GEE's 'javascript dictionary' format ( GEE outputs a csv with a single .geo column containing data of the form {"type":"Point","coordinates":[107.35873495689798,15.07126214132908]} ), and then throw this data on the map using ggmap(basement)+geom_point() it displays correctly.)

The raster I am trying to overlay on a stamenmap basemap has the following properties:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1800, 4008, 7214400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.08983153, 0.08983153  (x, y)
extent     : -180.0044, 180.0403, -76.77901, 84.91774  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

I have tried reprojecting this to Google PseudoMercator (EPSG:3857) with no luck. **How do I fix what appears to be a CRS problem, and get my raster data on my stamenmap, when the stamenmap basemap has no CRS?**

Comment: I would say don't use `ggmap`. I think the `tmap` package should be able to get a stamen basemap via `tm_basemap` and then you can layer on your raster with `tm_raster`. Will up this comment to an answer if I get time to work through the details. In fact one of the examples in `tm_basemap` *is* "StamenWatercolor"

Comment: `tmap` will plot my raster on a basemap when `tmap_mode('view')` is called, but not when I call `tmap_mode('plot')`. Since I'm trying to make a (static) graphic for publication this is frustrating. .... time for a return to QGIS?. Just to be clear, the call to plot a raster I am using is `tm_basemap('somebasemapID')+tm_shape('some raster file')+tm_raster()`

Comment: Update: see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903210/how-to-add-a-basemap-to-a-tmap-plot-in-r). Tmap only lets you pull a third-party basemap in view mode, so this is not a good solution for my problem.

Comment: See my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347863/tmap-basemap-in-plot-mode

Comment: Nice! That works. I'd like to accept this as an answer because it solves my problem, but I think (?) I should leave this open because the q posed in the post (which is about a technical issue in ggmap) is not addressed.

Comment: Then I guess your Q is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227182/how-to-set-use-ggplot2-to-map-a-raster since ggmap() is just ggplot() in disguise..

Comment: no, because my question is about the nature of the (oddly crs-less?) basemap returned by get_stamenmap. But thank you for the tmap suggestion and crossref - I've upvoted both.

Comment: Its not a "basemap" that can be used in anything apart from `ggmap`. You can't reproject it, scale it, or use it with any other plotting function (without ripping its guts out). It doesn't play nicely with any of the rest of the R spatial infrastructure which is why I never recommend using it!