# Load tiles from ArcGIS MapServer into R

Tags: r, arcgis-server, tiles

I am attempting to load static tiles from this [ArcGIS MapServer](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RTK5Unh1Z71JKIiR/arcgis/rest/services?f=html&cacheKey=8d6e5fd6590042ca) into R, and generate static maps with `tmap 3.3`.
The package has a pretty convenient way to do this in `view`-mode, generating interactive maps.

```
url_tile_services <- "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RTK5Unh1Z71JKIiR/arcgis/rest/services/"
tile_example <- "Global_Dam_Watch/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

data("World")

## Interactive map
tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_tiles(paste0(url_tile_services, tile_example), group = "LABELS") +
  tm_symbols(size = "gdp_cap_est")
```

Conversely, the method to map static tiles in `plot`-mode, i.e. returning static maps, is rather unclear. In fact the code below returns the symbols layer but not the tiles layer. Unfortunately, neither a `Warning` nor an `Error` message is returned, and this makes the troubleshooting more challenging because I have no idea of what's going wrong.

```
url_tile_services <- "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RTK5Unh1Z71JKIiR/arcgis/rest/services/"
tile_example <- "Global_Dam_Watch/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

data("World")

## Static map
tmap_mode("plot")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_tiles(paste0(url_tile_services, tile_example), group = "LABELS") +
  tm_symbols(size = "gdp_cap_est")
```

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347863/tmap-basemap-in-plot-mode) and this [issue raised on the GitHub](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/185) deal with this matter but all suggested solutions focus on OpenStreetMap tiles, while I need several from those provided in the MapServer linked above to produce static maps.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you really need tiles out to the N and S pole? Many tile servers struggle with those limits because they have tiles based on Web Mercator projections, and tiles aren't well defined there. I can create basemaps from your service URL for smaller regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `tm_tiles` in plot mode. The help for that function suggests `read_osm` but I've used functions from `rosm`.

The trick is to grab a raster image and use `tm_rgb`.

For a custom tile service, you have to use the `as.tile_source` function from the `rosm` package. Since yours doesn't have an extension in the path, you have to explicitly say what kind of images are returned:

```
gdw  = rosm::as.tile_source("https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RTK5Unh1Z71JKIiR/arcgis/rest/services/Global_Dam_Watch/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}",
       extension="png")
```

Then get a raster. Full-world rasters out to the North pole usually fail for tile servers that use web mercator because the tiles are infinitely big. So you can't do that. Trim the poles off if you can. You use `rosm::osm.raster` to get the tiles, join them into a single image, and transform them to the coordinate system of the bounding box object:

Here's an example for Africa:

```
> Africa = subset(World, continent=="Africa")
> africabase <- osm.raster(as(Africa,"Spatial"), crop=FALSE, type=gdw)
Zoom: 4
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> tm_shape(africabase) + tm_rgb() + tm_shape(World) +  tm_symbols(col="red",size = "gdp_cap_est") + tm_layout(legend.outside=TRUE)
```

[image]

If you don't want the transformation done on the raster, do it on the bounding box object, transforming to Web Mercator (3857):

```
africabase <- osm.raster(as(st_transform(Africa,3857),"Spatial"), crop=FALSE, type=gdw)
```

which leads to:

[image]

If you try this with a full latitude range you get this mess:

[image]

as the infinite tiles start to affect things at the poles...

`read_osm` for your tile service seems to fail:

```
> url = "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RTK5Unh1Z71JKIiR/arcgis/rest/services/Global_Dam_Watch/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
> osm_NLD <- read_osm(NLD_muni, ext=1.1, type=url)
Error in col2rgb(x$colorData) : invalid RGB specification
```

which I might track down the root cause of...

Comment: Brilliant. The maps I am going to create are supposed to have global coverage but cutting off few degrees latitude at the poles won't be an issue. Would you expect that a +88 -88 latitudinal extent would be sufficient to overcome the issue?

Comment: Web Mercator is only specified valid between 85S and 85N. OpenStreetMap and GoogleMaps limit themselves to 85N/S. You may have to try and find a global basemap in a non-mercator projection with polar support, like a sinusoidal projection. Do you really need the zoomable abilities of a tile service or would a static world map work?

Comment: The static map is the one in question, the interactive map was easy to generate with `tm_tiles` in `view`-mode (code above). I am not sure I understand why do I need a non-mercator projection though. I thought of using a bbox 85N, 85S as my data are all within that latitudinal range. Maybe something like `prettymapr::makebbox(85, 180, -85, -180)` . For the moment I am using the extent of my vector layer so I haven't tried the bbox solution yet.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted to create static map images given any set of bounds. A mercator projection up to 88N/S will have massive distortion near the poles. 85 degrees gets you a square mercator projection - 88 degrees and the world will be much much taller than wide - like the last image in my answer!

Comment: I understand. Those 88N/S I mentioned before have created some confusion. Eventually I can stick to the limits of the mercator projection. Thank you @spacedman for the valuable hints!